# Setting a variable to the result of Workbooks.Open

Tags: excel, vba

Below is what I have but I get an error

> Compile Error: Expected end of statement.

```
Set galreqws = Workbooks.Open FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\galreq.xlsx"
```

Comment: If you use an if statement, it looks like an error with no end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting a var to the result of the Workbooks.Open method, bracket your parameters.

```
dim galreqws as workbook    'could also be dim galreqws as object
Set galreqws = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\galreq.xlsx")

'alternate
with  Workbooks.Open(FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\galreq.xlsx")
    debug.print .name
    debug.print .fullname
    debug.print .worksheets(1).name
    'work with galreq.xlsx here
end with
```

If you are not setting an object var then leave the brackets out.

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\galreq.xlsx"
```

Comment: user10825204 Used your first option but still came back with error "Run-time error '13: Type mismatch." Could that be caused by a Dim or Set somewhere else in my code or is something else causing it?

Answer (score 0):

No ***space*** after *This*:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\qwerty.xlsm"
    Set galreqws = ActiveWorkbook
End Sub
```

basically replace:

```
This workbook.Path
```

with:

```
ThisWorkbook.Path
```

*(I use two lines of code to avoid confusing myself)*

Comment: The problem is by splitting it up, the workbook that gets opened isn't the ActiveWorkbook so it gives me an error "Run-time error '13: Type mismatch" when it gets to your second line. Suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a Dim statement relating to galreqws earlier in your code?